# Joomla Jdatabase query code with join does not work

Tags: mysql, joomla

I run the php code below within the 'Eval' section of a Fabrik form element. The code is supposed to return/put a number in a form field, but nothing appears in the form field.

When I used another query (refer to '$query-> ' lines) the code does work, so I get the impression that the query contains errors; however, when executing the related webpage with the form fields no sql error appears.

I have no idea what is wrong with the query(?)

Code:

```
$form_productname = 'testproduct';
$form_username = 'myname';

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

//$query->select($db->quoteName(array('a.id', 'b.productid')));
$query->select($db->quoteName('b.productid'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__products', 'b')); 
$query->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__extendedreg_users', 'a') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.user_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.owner') . ') 
AND (' . $db->quoteName('a.cf_collectivename') . ' = ' . $db->quote($form_username) . ') 
AND (' . $db->quoteName('b.productname') . ' = ' . $db->quote($form_productname)).')'.;
//echo $query;exit;
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();

$results = $db->loadObjectList();
return count($results);
```

UPDATE: cause was syntax php error in where statement:

```
. $db->quote($form_productname)).
```

must be:

```
. $db->quote($form_productname).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting any errors because you are not catching any errors.  Have a look at [How to do SQL exception / error handling](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/495/how-to-do-sql-exception-error-handling-compatible-with-2-5-and-3-x).

Do at least a `$query->dump()` and run your query in a console if you can't figure out what is wrong.

I don't understand why are you quoting the value you are comparing `$form_username` and `$form_productname`. But maybe it's late and I am tired.

Comment: thnx. Just a beginners question: I added the line 'echo $query->dump()'. But where is the echoed query supposed to appear? On the webpage of the form I dont see it...

Comment: In should appear near the HTML output of your extension (anyway, somewhere in the page).

Comment: it doesnt;-(. Not sure whether that's because I use particular template (Purity III)

Comment: It seems that the Jommla purity III template that I use somehow surpresses/hides the echoed lines...;-( Not sure yet how to solve that...

Comment: Suggestion to use debugger is good (for own developed components I use Netbeans); however, the shown code is somehow somehwere embbedded within the Fabrik framework and I would not have a clue where to look...;-(

Comment: Sometimes you have to put a die; after the echo to be able to see it; at least that is what I do.

Comment: Finally got everything sorted; I used the debugger (thnx for tip!) and noticed a php syntax error in where statement. Once the code is php error free, echoed lines show up as well - also with Purity iii template. Thnx again for your comments (!)